# Categorize data and assign new data

Tags: r

I am processing data and I specifically want to categorize it using intervals.

`cut` command comes extremely useful, as I can use, for example,

```
data <- seq(1, 10)
cut(data, 2)
>> [1] (0.991,5.5] (0.991,5.5] (0.991,5.5] (0.991,5.5] (0.991,5.5] (5.5,10]    (5.5,10]    (5.5,10]    (5.5,10]    (5.5,10]
Levels: (0.991,5.5] (5.5,10]
```

To categorize the data in two intervals. The processing is part of a more complex problem, and eventually new data is going to need to be assigned to the intervals, that are automatically generated.

What is the most efficient way to do this? Because trying to read `levels()` to classify seems too dirty...

Comment: Have a look at `findInterval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick way using base R:

```
# Find intervals use original data
labs = levels(cut(data, 2))
labs_df = cbind(lower = as.numeric( sub("\\((.+),.*", "\\1", labs) ),
      upper = as.numeric( sub("[^,]*,([^]]*)\\]", "\\1", labs) ))

# Find intervals on new data
data_new = sample(1:10)
interval_idx = findInterval(data_new, labs_df[,1])
interval_idx

interval = labs[interval_idx]

data.frame(data_new, interval_idx, interval)
```